# Android artifacts, Action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, artifacts

I have no idea why there are arifacts on ActionBar.
It looks like that:

[image: artifacts]

Application style defined in Manifest:

```
android:style/Theme.Holo
```

in Activity:

```
ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

How to fix that.

Comment: [Disable screen compatibility](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html#Disable) mode to see if it changes or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a Background to the ActionBar:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.screen_background_dark));
```

That did it for me;